# ReactJS - How to log the specific field that is causing a 400 error code when submitting form

Tags: javascript, django, reactjs, django-rest-framework

I am currently working on a web app that uses ReactJS as the frontend, and DRF as the backend, and I am working on the form validation right now. In the backend, for fields that are phone numbers, I am using PhoneNumber field, which is a Django library that interfaces with python-phonenumbers to validate phone numbers keyed in. Hence, I was thinking that it would be best if I do my form validation based on the response from the DRF api post request, since it would be tough for me to come up with a regex that completely complies with the PhoneNumber field's requirement. Hence, I am trying to figure out if it is possible for the axios error response to specifically tell me which field is causing the 400 error code. If so, I can then display the relevant error like 'This is not a phone number' above the relevant fields. Or if not, is there any better way for me to handle this and be able to align completely with the PhoneNumber field's requirements? Basically I do not want to run into an issue where the phone number passes the ReactJS form validation but fails the Django PhoneNumber field's requirements, and the form just fails to submit, without any indication of why (if I have the field and the error code, I can then deduce that it is due to the phone number being invalid, and display the necessary errors on the screen from there). I noticed that when using Postman to make API calls, it is able to tell me specifically which field is causing the error, and I was wondering if Axios can do the same?

Currently this is my .catch for the axios post request, and all it does is show me the error code and some other irrelevant information.

```
 .catch(error => {
        console.log(error.toJSON());
        })
```

Below is the model I am trying to validate. The three fields below are the fields I have rendered in the form in ReactJS, and they would all be submitted under 1 API post request, which is why the specific field causing the error is important in knowing which field I should render an error message on so that the end user knows that he needs to change that specific field as it is an invalid phone number.

```
class CustomerInformation(models.Model):
   customer_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   telephone_number = PhoneNumberField(blank=True)
   telephone_number_backup = PhoneNumberField(blank=True)
```

All help is welcome and appreciated, thank you in advance! I am new to ReactJS hence I am not sure if my intended solution is appropriate, please do guide me in the correct direction if I am wrong!

Comment: Have you tried axios' interceptors? https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors

Comment: No I have not, but can I check how would interceptors help me in this scenario? I want it to send to the server side and then use the server side's error response to validate the phone number field, the only issue is that I do not know which field is causing the 400 error code, hence I am not able to make use of the error response of axios. Sorry I am new to ReactJS so I might be a bit clueless! Do correct me if I am wrong, appreciate your reply :-)

Comment: I might not understand properly the question. So there are multiple phone number inputs (or any other input), each making a call to the API?

Comment: sorry, I realised I did not clarify on that, I editted the question above to house the relevant information about the form and the model in Django. Yes there are multiple phone number inputs in that same form and model, and there is only 1 API call made, which consist of data from the entire form, and hence it is necessary for me to know which specific field is causing the 400 error code so that I can render the relevant error message so that the end user knows which field he needs to change.

Comment: It sounds like you need to change your backend rather than frontend part of the app

Comment: oh meaning that I have to alter my backend such that the error code comes back in a way that would specify the field that causes the error? okay i will go and look into it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, took some time and googling but figured it out, I can find the specifics of the error under error.response data.

This is what I did to my axios call (btw I am using DRF so im not sure if it would work for other backend systems)

```
.catch(error => {
       console.log(error.response.data)
  )}
```

Which would log out the errors flagged out by the backend when trying to post the request. 
It comes in the form of an object, with the keys of the object as the field name, and the value of the corresponding key would be an array of the errors flagged out.

For example, the error message I got was:

```
{telephone_number: ["The phone number entered is not valid."]}
```

From there, I was able to render the relevant error messages onto the relevant fields by matching the key of the object to the name of the field.

Hope this has helped some people, it certainly helped me!